# Angular custom service call fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I have been following a tutorial online on PluralSight for working with Angular, however it appears that some of the information is outdated.

I have reached a section on creating custom services and have followed the tutorial to the letter however my custom service will not work correctly.

It seems to fail when I try to call my github service, it looks like the promise fails to return correctly to the script.js `.then()` handler for `github.getUser()`

The plunk for it is here http://plnkr.co/edit/8vy6ZMpUJBfEOQ3qFoKk

Can someone please tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want just to get it to work, here's how to fix it:

Your second option is to add a return to your `$http` on the service, like this:

```
var getUser = function(username) {
  return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    });
};
```

Note that you only forgot the first "return" before the $http. The rest was working well

A better way to solve that would be to not resolve your promise inside the service. That way you get a thin service and can manage your data as you like within your controller.

So I changed your getUser to this:

```
var getUser = function(username) {
  return $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + username);
};
```

This way it returns the entire promise from `$http`. Since I removed your "wrapper" I need to modify your `onUserComplete ()` too:

```
var onUserComplete = function(result) {
  $scope.user = result.data;
  github.getRepos($scope.user).then(onRepos, onError);
};
```

Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8abkaU08fCzFreA5APz1?p=info

Comment: ahhh excellent pickup on the missing return, I have it working now :) thanks for the help!